# Lightning: how to get dynamic scrolling height work?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am trying to implement scrolling in Lightning app with standard Lightning SLDS styles and it is not working.

I tried both ui:scrollerWrapper and class="slds-scrollable--y" and neither of these is working.
The right panel in my picture consists on static div element with height h1 and dynamic div element with height h2 which should use all the remaining space (basically speaking h2 should be "clientHeight - h1".

[image]

I don't want to use custom javascript for this.

When I use some custom css it almost works but it breaks when I try to combine it with slds--grid.

Does anyone knows if this is possible to achieve using standard Lightning slds styling or components?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or recreate this problem on a hosted web page?

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't support lightning...

Comment: How about a public facing lightning app then?